# custom list style not working with wordwrap, dont know why

Tags: css, wordpress, list

Another problem like you see in the picture. The padding-right does not work for wordwrap and if I change position to absolute the padding is deleted.

[image]

on this site: http://neuronade.com/kopie-sdfsdf-3

```css
ul.iconhaken li:before{
     content: '✔';
     color: green;
                          font-weight: bold;
     margin-left: -1em;
     margin-right: .100em;
                                        padding-right: 5%;
                                        position: relative;
    }
    ul.iconhaken {
     list-style-type: none;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="iconhaken">
 <li>Jede Uni hat Seelsorge-Stellen. Erkundige dich dort mal. Alternativ kannst du über folgende Website per Mail oder per Chat eine kostenlose Beratung erhalten.</li>
 <li>Jetzt bist du optimal auf deine Prüfungen vorbereitet. Also Ruhe bewahren und viel Erfolg!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with the code you have provided. Please can you clarify what conditions are required to see the issue (for example, what browser are you using?) or modify the code so that it demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the checkmark to absolute element and set the padding on the `li` element:

```css
ul.iconhaken li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5%;
}


ul.iconhaken li:before {
  content: '✔';
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul.iconhaken {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="iconhaken">
  <li>Jede Uni hat Seelsorge-Stellen. Erkundige dich dort mal. Alternativ kannst du über folgende Website per Mail oder per Chat eine kostenlose Beratung erhalten.</li>
  <li>Jetzt bist du optimal auf deine Prüfungen vorbereitet. Also Ruhe bewahren und viel Erfolg!</li>
</ul>
```